# Using webpacks raw-loader to read markdown files results in contents of index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, markdown

I'm trying to use markdown-to-jsx to display markdown files in my react app, but it keeps rendering the index.html file.

In my webpack.config I have:

```
{
    test: /\.md$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "raw-loader",
        options: {
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
    ],
},
```

and then in my react component I have tried both:
`const GettingStartedMD = require("./userguide.md");`
and
 `import GettingStartedMD from "./userguide.md";`

and then in my component I have:

```
const DisplayAbout = () => {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] = useState("");
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(GettingStartedMD)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((text) => setMarkdown(text))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
  return (
    <Container className={clsx(classes.root)}>
      {markdown && <Markdown children={markdown} />}
...
```

But the result of the fetch and .text() is always the contents of the index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I used the import directly and it worked. I was getting the proper markdown after importing. Fetch simply requests for a non-existing file which defaults to index.html in dev mode.

```
import GettingStartedMD from "./GettingStartedMD.md";

export const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>{GettingStartedMD}</div>
  )
}
```